# How can I derive a mathematical pattern from my data by adding more code to compile a formula of some sort?

Tags: math, pattern-matching, formula, python-3.6

Currently the code I am using outputs a value and a corresponding list of how many combinations there are for the sum of that value, using values greater than 0 and less than the value. The number of combinations increases at a large rate but I would like to use python to find a trend and hopefully derive an equation from the data.

```
def a(lst, target, with_replacement=False):
    def _a(idx, l, r, t, w):
        if t == sum(l): r.append(l)
        elif t < sum(l): return
        for u in range(idx, len(lst)):
            _a(u if w else (u + 1), l + [lst[u]], r, t, w)
        return r
    return _a(0, [], [], target, with_replacement)

for val in range(1,101):
    s = range(1, val)
    solutions = a(s, val)
    #print(solutions)
    print('Value:', val, "Combinations", len(solutions))
```

Comment: You could use Python to find the first 20 or so values of your sequence (you are doing 100) and type those values into the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/) and look at the results. Your sequence may already be there--and in your particular case it probably is. Look at the details of the sequence, and if there is a formula it should be in the details.

Comment: In fact, [here is the sequence](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C7%2C9%2C11%2C14%2C17%2C21%2C26%2C31%2C37%2C45%2C53%2C63&language=english&go=Search). In the `Formula` section there are multiple formulas but none that you would probably call a mathematical "equation." There is a formula with a straightforward summation and product: is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: that is what I was looking for, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.